# Is there a way to debug the PostCreateCommand in VSCode Devcontainers?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I am currently having this issue:

```sh
Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh
```

which is the

```json
    "postCreateCommand": "./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh",
```

setting from the `devcontainer.json`.

But the script works when I deactivate the "postCreateCommand" and run it manually after container creation. Which made me think, that the issue might be the path to the script somehow. But that is not the case either. Since an empty script with just an echo command seems to work.

The script is the following:

```sh
echo "Installing Developer Requirements"

apt-get update && apt-get install -y man git
pip3 install -r .devcontainer/dev_pip_requirements.txt
```

Any ideas how to debug the `"PostCreateCommand"`? The output is less than helpful and I don't want to start reducing this project into a minimum working example.

I changed git to checkout everything with linux file endings on windows.  And I triple checked that the shell script has LF endings. So those should not be an issue either. (They were previously).

Comment: The output can be seen in the container logs ("Remote-Containers: Show Container log")

Answer (score 7):

I think that one cause may be that the user does not have enough permissions to even execute the `apt-get update` command.

Changing the `remoteUser` to `root`, in the `devcontainer.json` configuration file should allow to execute the `postCreateCommand.sh` shell script successfully when running it using `bash`.

- I've tried it using the `python:3.8-slim-buster` Docker image, having set a `non-root` user in the `Dockerfile`.
- I've added the following to the `./.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`:

  ```json
  "postCreateCommand": "bash ./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh",
  "remoteUser": "root",
  ```
- I've used the following `./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh`:

  ```sh
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  set -ex

  apt-get update && apt-get install -y man git && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

  pip install --requirement ./.devcontainer/dev_pip_requirements.txt
  ```

Generally, `root` is not recommended for production environments.

Here is a little more information about `postCreateCommand`

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1685#issuecomment-542950190
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1685#issuecomment-543895263

Comment: I actually solved this particular issue much later and forgot I asked: The problem was that the script was not executable. `chmod +x` solved the problem. But this does not answer the question if there is a way to debug vscode devcontainers

Answer (score 2):

We experienced the same issue recently. Took me a big while to discover this question with no answer. We came across an ugly solution and here's what we did:

1. In your `devcontainer.json`, add the following:

```json
"mounts": ["type=bind,source=/home/runner/logs,target=/var/logs"],
```

2. Change your commands. In your case:

```
- "postCreateCommand": "./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh",
+ "postCreateCommand": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/sh ./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh >> 2>&1 /var/logs/garbage.log"],
```

Finally, if the container exploded, `cat /home/runner/logs/*.log`.
You might as well need to run `chown /var/logs`, or just make it `0777`.

Alternatively, you do something like

```
- "postCreateCommand": "./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh",
+ "postCreateCommand": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "(/bin/sh ./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh >> 2>&1 /var/logs/garbage.log) || (echo lmao)"],
```

So that the script never fail.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, Codespaces now logs this for you: **Cmd/CTRL + Shift + P** to view them

[image]

The log file is located at `/workspaces/.codespaces/.persistedshare/creation.log`