# VS Code and Docker Desktop - refer to project folder in Dockerfile and postCreate install

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

When I start a container from VS Code, it gets its own workspace folder, e.g.
`/workspaces/d2`.  Can I refer to the workspace path in RUN commands in `Dockerfile`? I will have some build steps that need to be done in a sub-directory.

I tried to set an environment variable `PROJECT` and this partly works.

My simple example files are: devcontainer.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "context": "..",
  "dockerFile": "./Dockerfile",

   "build": {
    "args": {
      "PROJECT": "${containerWorkspaceFolder}"
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:22.04
# LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors="steve@espops.com"

# Pass in the current project workspace directory, which VS Code establishes
ARG PROJECT

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN echo ${PROJECT} >out.txt
```

```
pwd
/workspaces/d2

cat /out.txt 
/workspaces/d2
```

However when I add build instructions to work in that folder, I get errors saying it doesn't exist.

This can be seen using:

```
ENV PROJECT=${PROJECT}
RUN echo $PROJECT >out.txt
RUN bash -c ls -l $PROJECT >>out.txt
```

The file out.txt shows the expected variable value, but `ls` shows the contents of `/`, not the project folder, which after all initialisation is complete, shows correctly in an interactive shell.

Can the `Dockerfile` wait for VS Code to create those folders - or does it always have to finish before VS Code creates them?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. `Dockerfile` has to finish, then VS Code initialises its extensions etc.

However I found a way using the VSCode `postCreateCommand` (see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container#_rebuild)) also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909781/is-there-a-way-to-debug-the-postcreatecommand-in-vscode-devcontainers).

In `devcontainer.json`, add:

```
  "postCreateCommand": "./post_create.sh"
```

Create a script in the home folder of the project, with `+x` privilege, e.g.

post_create.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo Building Go plugin:
cd auth-plugin-go && go build -buildmode c-shared -o auth.so auth.go && cd ..
```

On container rebuild, after other steps are complete, the script runs in a terminal window.
[image]

Looks like you always get the `sh` shell regardless of any shebang at the start of the .sh file, so you may want to invoke `bash` at the start of the `postCreateCommand` attribute.